# force WCF channel to ip address

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, channel

I have two computers and they are connected via ethernet, i have set up an WCF connection and this all works ok, however when i host the same wcf on the local pc as the one i want to comunicate to and then do a wcf request via a channel, the request does not go to the remote pc but to my local pc. Is there a way to force a wcf request from a channel to go trough a specific ipaddress and not just go to any?

i'll try to explain how i use this:

there are two computers they are both similar and have two network adapters who have the same ipaddess and run thesame wcf software. so for example ipaddress for adapter 1 is: 10.10.10.1 and the other adapter is 10.10.10.2 on the same pc, and the other pc is similar. now these two pc need to communicate so i wire the two network adapters in cross example: pc 1 network adapter one goes to pc 2 network adapter 2. this so they are connected in 2 ways. so if i want to communicate with a simple socket from one to the other and back over the second adapter this all goes ok becouse i can bind a socket to a ipaddress and it will send it via the adapter it is bound to. but this does not seem to work with WCF. if i have two hosts on one pc, one for adapter 10.10.10.1 and one on 10.10.10.2 for the other adapter and i send a message to 10.10.10.2 that is on the remote pc, it will go in via the second network adapeter.

```
PC1 network adapter 1 (10.10.10.1) <--direct patch cable connection--> PC2 network adapter 2 (10.10.10.2)

PC1 network adapter 2 (10.10.10.2) <--direct patch cable connection--> PC2 network adapter 1 (10.10.10.1)
```

These connection arrows are direct connection patch cables!

all network adapters have a wcf hosted, and the software on both pc's is thesame.

this is all done for redundancy, more then two pc can be connected in a chain with this.

this is a little example of how i setup a request to the remote host:

```
public void Test()
        {
            string endPoint = "net.tcp://10.10.10.2:9985/connection";

            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            binding.ListenBacklog = 2000;
            binding.MaxConnections = 2000;
            binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 104857600;
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            //binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
            //binding.PortSharingEnabled = false;

            ChannelFactory<Connection> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<Connection>(binding, new EndpointAddress(endPoint));

            var pipeProxy = this.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            //fictional method: pipeProxy.SendRequestTunnelTo("10.10.10.1"); //this is the ipaddress that it should go out to however it goes out to "10.10.10.2" 
            //and this is another network adapter also on the local mashine and here is also a wcf host on

            ((IClientChannel)pipeProxy).AllowOutputBatching = true;
            ((IClientChannel)pipeProxy).Open();

            pipeProxy.SystemRequest(); //do function
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify... You don't mean that a two IP addresses are being shared between 4 NICs across two computers? Eg does the other machine have .3 and .4 addresses?

Comment: I updated my post, the ipaddresses on both pc's are thesame. and the addresses are connected in cross like in the example.

Comment: From your updated diagram, unless those two PCs are on different subnets with NAT happening in between, that's not a valid network setup. An IP address should be uniquely assigned. What if a 3rd computer tried to ping 10.10.10.2? Which one would you expect to respond? Is there a reason you're trying to share the IPs like this? There might be a better way to achieve your goal

Comment: @Basic I'm sorry i forgot to mention that the connections you see are direct, so it are just two patch cable bitween the two adapters/pc's. so there is no double ipaddress, it is just a direct  network connection to the pc's (ip 10.10.10.1 is connected to the other pc 10.10.10.2 adapter and in reverse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue here is routing. If windows thinks it can deliver the traffic directly to the other IP Address, it will do so.

In this case, it can't differentiate between the local 10.10.10.2 that it knows about and one that's on another network hidden behind a NAT.

The preferred solution is to not use the same subnet (so have 10.10.10.2 and 10.11.10.2 or similar), however that can sometimes require significant changes.

The next best option is to use the IP address of the NAT and have it port forward.

Say you have a setup like this (where the boxes with 2 ip addresses are NATing routers with both public and internal IPs)...

```
10.10.10.2 --- [10.10.10.1 | 1.2.3.4] --- Internet --- [5.6.7.8 | 10.10.10.1] -- 10.10.10.2
```

Then the machine on the left should try to connect to 5.6.7.8 which should forward connections to the machine on the right (and vice-versa with the right machine connecting to 1.2.3.4).

If you've got a WAN setup that makes the machines appear to be in the same network, that's as much of a problem as being on the same network. None of the routers on the network will be able to determine which 10.10.10.2 you mean,

If you weren't using *exactly* the same IP address, you might be able to force the issue using routing tables on your windows box. This can allow you to specify preferential routes so that all traffic for a given IP address goes out over the specified NIC. Unfortunately, beyond that point it's out of your control and entirely up to the network hardware how the packets are routed. If you have the ability to configure routing on the intermediate hardware, you could fix the route the whole way to the destination but this is usually an awful lot of work and likely to be broken when kit is updated/replaced as it's non-standard.

If you decide to look into forcing routes, start with the Windows [route command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true)

**Edit:** Re: Forcing routing over an interface...

the syntax is `route add target mask gateway costmetric interfaceid`

run `route print` at a command prompt and make a note of the interface id you want to use form the top of the output

then add a route like this:

```
route add 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.255 10.10.10.2 1 [interface id from above]
```

on my machine that would be

```
route add 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.255 10.10.10.2 1 11
```

Note that in this case we're telling it to use 10.0.0.2 as a gateway. I have no idea what the consequences of doing this will be as software attempting to access itself via a locally bound port might get very confused. Last caveat: I don't have a pair of physical machines to hand that I can test this on, and VMs don't really count as their networking is slightly different.

We're providing a cost metric of 1. This should give it a very high priority meaning it should be chosen above all other routes to that IP address.

The route will be lost when the system reboots. You can use a `-p` flag after `route add` to make the route persistent. I suggest you don't do this until you're sure it's working as intended.

**2nd Edit:** I think you're heading down a rabbit hole here. While it may be possible to trick the system into working this way, it's definitely not a common usage and I haven't been able to find anything that says it's supported.

It seems like your fundamental problem is that you've got no way to negotiate before assigning IP addresses as you have no network connectivity.

Some thoughts...

Sharing the IP is not going to be robust, so decouple from it. Instead of using a fixed IP in the url, determine the other IP address programatically.

You could have two builds, one which uses .1/.2 and the other which uses .3/.4. Any build1 could then talk to any build2 but not 1-1 or 2-2. This is a bit awkward but would work with little effort on your part.

Better would be to assign unique IPs to every machine you build, then provide a way to detect the other machine's address. [Service location protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Location_Protocol) is a likely candidate for this approach. Once you  know the IP address you need to communicate with, configuring WCF should be trivial.

If assigning unique IPs is problematic, you could potentially have DHCP servers on all nodes but only turn them on if another one doesn't exist on that network (pair). That way, every machine would end up with valid IP addresses with no prior configuration.

Comment: I posted this before reading your latest comment. I'm just about to go into a meeting but will come back and update if I can think of a better option. Unfortunately, I haven't done networking without at least a router in ~15 years so I'll need to have a ponder. Routing tables might still be an option. While I'm away, is there a reason not to use a router and give the 4 NICs different IP Addresses? Oh and can you please edit your Q to include the output of `route print` on one/both machines (Interface list/IPv4 only)

Comment: if i use two difrent network subnets, the problem is solved indeed. however this would realy mess up the design idea behind the redundency software. the reson for the direct connection and not via a router is the extra point of failure, this communication line connects two (or three) servers (that realy just stand next to each other) so they can share data fast, and with little chance of failure, becouse of the two direct patch cables, and the design of the software.

Comment: @ Basic however i dont think that routing is the problem, i suspect that the WCF request channel goes and look for the endpoint '10.10.10.2:9985' and sees it on its own networkadapter, and the does not look further for the possibility that it can be a remote pc connected to the other network card.

Comment: @Jeff You're right about the problem but that _is_ a routing issue. If you look at the output of `route print` you'll probably notice that `10.10.10.2` is marked as `On-link` which means don't bother going to the network at all, it's an address owned by a local interface. We should be able to force a route that says go over interface [x]. Where it gets interesting is that the machines then couldn't use their own local IP addresses to talk to themselves (except loopback/127.0.0.1). The problem is, I'm not sure what the implications of that would be so I need to do some research

Comment: @ Basic The network adapter used for this communication is dedicated for this purpose, so no other communication can go over this network adapters. how can i force it over a specific interface? i'll go try it to see if it works.

Comment: I actually meant that an application might reasonably assume that if it binds to an IP address X, then it can talk to itself on X, not another machine. However... I've edited the answer with an example.

Comment: One other question for you... Is there a reason not to give each end of the crossover cable a different IP Address?

Comment: this software and hardware is going to be placed many times, and the best way for the engineers to place it, connect it and for there to be only one software packet, is that all servers are identical. I ame now trying to do the routing, and it seems to be working half, if i set one of the routing item for one network card, it seems to be working but not for the other connection, im now trying to find out why this is happening

Comment: At a guess (and it is only a guess), it sounds like you're getting into a circular redirection. `A` knows that 10.10.10.2 needs to be delivered to `B`. That works fine. When `B` sends a packet to the same IP address and delivers it to `A`, `A` forwards it back to `B` rather than accepting the packet. When `B` sees a packet it's already sent out, it doesn't send it out again. I suggest you fire up [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and watch what's actually happening on the wire. Also check the current routing table. Windows can modify them dynamically as it learns the network.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint address needs to identify the IP address you are targetting.

Comment: that ipaddres is the remote pc ipaddress, however the local pc also has another network adapter with thesame ip and the same host running. so i need to force it to go out on not that network adapter but on the other one.

Comment: Two machines on the same network with the same IP address is not going to work.

Comment: they are not on the same network, the two adapters are both on independent networks, talking to other hosts. the wcf request is not going out to a remote pc but becouse the other network adaptor also has the same target ipaddress the requst goes local and not remote.